# How to convert Object to "original" type

Tags: java, object, types, casting

I have the following code, where i get a `HashMap<String,Object>` which contains different datatypes as values (e.g. int, String, float) and want to cast the Object to its original type.

```
HashMap<String,Object> values = new HashMap<String,Object>;
values.put("Field1", 23);
values.put("Field2", "teststring");
values.put("Field3", 64.23f);

int a = (Integer)values.get("Field1");
String b = (String)values.get("Field2");
float c = (Float)values.get("Field3");
```

As you can see I know how to do this by typecasting, but is there a way to do this dynamically?

I know I can get the "original" type with `values.get("Field3").getClass();` but I don't know how to use it in order to solve my problem.

I have two `int`s in the query result and I want to know the sum of them. Therefore I have to cast the `Object`s to `int` and then build the sum. Next time I want to do the same thing, but instead of `int`s, the types are `float`s.

Comment: Suppose you could do what you're trying to do... What would you possibly do with the result? You can't possibly store it in a variable (because you don't know what type the variable would be) or do anything with it (because you don't know what type it is at compile time) or call a method with it (because the compiler wouldn't know which method to call, because it doesn't know the type).

Comment: @immibis The HashMap is a result of a database query. So in order to use this result i try to dynamically cast the individual fields back to their types.

Comment: Dynamically these objects already are of that particular type.

Comment: @maxkra I'm still not sure I understand. Can you show what your code would look like if it was possible? (make up some syntax for it)

Comment: @maxkra do you know that `Field1` is a `int`or do you need to detect its type?

Comment: Well for example I have two `int`s in the query result and i want to know @immibis the sum of them. Therefore I have to cast the `Object`s to `int` and then build the sum. Next time i want to do the same thing, but instead of `int`s, the types are `float`s. I dont want to change my code and recompile. But when I understand your previous comment the right way that is not possible.

Comment: @maxkra Something like `values.get("a") + values.get("b")`? I don't think there's a way to do that without writing out the whole thing for each possible type, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've correctly understood your problem, you should do something like this:

```
Object obj = values.get(fieldName);
if(obj instanceof Float){
  float f = (float) obj;
  // do what you need with a float
} else if(obj instanceof String){
  String s = (String) obj;
  // do what you need with a String
} ...
```

Types set and precedence depends on your task.

Comment: That is the right direction i was searching about. But there is no way to not have the if-then-else part for every possible type?

Comment: I think there is not. Java is strict enough about types, so you should  handle it manually. Polymorphism resolves types automatically, but your case isn't about it at all

Answer (score 1):

Please use instanceof operator like below.                                               
     `if(obj instanceof String){
          cast to string
       }
       else if(obj instanceof Integer){
           cast to int
       }`